Is it possible to trigger an Azure Pipeline run if a folder in another repository is updated?
I have a Repo A with some code on it. There is a large Repo B with some other code on it.
I want to trigger my Repo A to run a pipeline only when the App/SampleApp folder in Repo B gets updated on the main branch. I only want it to trigger when this folder gets updated, as there many other directories.
I've read some documentation and other questions online, but they seem more geared to a folder in the same repository. I want to trigger based of a change in a different repository folder.
Both of these repos are in the same project and organization.
Here is my yml:
resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: RepoB
      name: repo-b
      ref: main
      type: git

trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - main

  paths:
    include:
      - App/SampleApp/*

stages:
  - stage: Build
    jobs:
      - template: build.yml

Azure shows me I'm getting the correct repository when I go to my pipeline settings, but I don't think it's only getting the folder I want to trigger based on. I'm not sure how it would know which repo the path is referencing.

As mentioned by @jiawei, you should add trigger in your repository resource, and also add paths filter on target files.
But since both of these repos are in the same project and organization, simply use repo name without project name in repository name. I added comment on the yaml below:
trigger: none  

resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: RepoB
    type: git
    name: repo-b             # directly use repo name not project/reponame as it's in same project
    trigger:                 # add trigger to monitor on the target branch           
      branches:
        include:
          - main
      paths:                # add paths filter to monitor only target files
        include:
          - App/SampleApp/*

stages:
  - stage: Build
    jobs:
      - job: job1
        steps:
          - checkout: RepoB
      #- template: build.yml

Pipeline will be triggered when App/SampleApp/* file changes on repo-b.


Azure shows me I'm getting the correct repository when I go to my pipeline settings, but I don't think it's only getting the folder I want to trigger based on.

The checkout task will fetch whole repo-b content but not only App/SampleApp/ folder. if you would like to only get the target folder content, you can use git command(sparse-checkout) instead. Change the yaml as below, please replace organization name, project name and repo name to yours.
trigger: none

resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: RepoB
    type: git
    name: repo-b
    trigger:
      branches:
        include:
          - main
      paths:
        include:
          - App/SampleApp/*

stages:
  - stage: Build
    jobs:
      - job: job1
        steps:
          - script: |
               mkdir repo-b && cd repo-b
               git init
               git config core.sparseCheckout true
               echo "App/SampleApp/" >> .git/info/sparse-checkout
               git pull https://user:$(system.accesstoken)@dev.azure.com/{orgname}/{projectname}/_git/repo-b main
          - script: |
               find repo-b -print         # check the content
      #- template: build.yml

Only App/SampleApp content from repo-b fetched.


For example, you have RepoA and RepoB in the same project myProject.
repositories:
  - repository: A
    type: git
    name: myProject/RepoA


  - repository: B
    type: git
    name: myProject/RepoB
    trigger:
      branches:
        include:
          - main
      paths:
        include:
          - app/*
        
steps:
- checkout: A
- bash: |
    echo "I clone the repoA here"

The pipeline will only be triggered when RepoB gets updated on the main branch in folder App/SampleApp.
And It will checkout the RepoA, so that you could use the source code in RepoA to run your pipeline.
More info you could refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/multi-repo-checkout?view=azure-devops#triggers
